# NHibernate - How to map a table with multiple foreign keys to its corresponding classes?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, composite

I have the following tables :

[image]

Basically, a user is part of a project and has certain access rights on that particular project.

I created the following entities:

1. User
2. Project
3. AccessRight

How can I map, using NHibernate, a User entity so that I can easily fetch the access rights per project he's assigned to ?

I was thinking of doing the following:

1. Create a new entity called "ProjectRight" which will have a Project ID as the primary key
2. Create a "Many-To-Many" set within the User entity :

   `public virtual ICollection<ProjectRight> ProjectRights { get; set; }`

   And in the User mapping:

> ```
> <set name="ProjectRights" table="Users_Projects_Rights">
>   <key column="id_UserGroup"></key>
>   <many-to-many class="ProjectRight" >
>     <column name="id_Project" />
>     <column name="id_AccessRight" />
>   </many-to-many>
>  </set>
> ```

Would this work ? And if yes, does that mean that I'll need to create two additional entities so that I can map the Projects and AccessRights table..?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating `ProjectRight` as a component instead of an entity:

```
<set name="ProjectRights" table="Users_Projects_Rights">
    <key column="id_User"/>
    <composite-element class="ProjectRight">
        <many-to-one name="Project" column="id_Project"/>
        <many-to-one name="Right" column="id_AccessRight"/>
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

This is one of the two ways suggested by the NHibernate documentation. For the other one see [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ternary).

Comment: Thanks Cremor, that's exactly what I was looking for. In the User entitty class, how do I define the set ? I can't use an ICollection since I don't have a ProjectRight entity.

Comment: Figured it out, I defined the set as an IDictionary: public virtual IDictionary<Project, AccessRight> AccessRights { get; set; }

Comment: @Hussein Dictionary is the other way (that I linked). If you use the mapping I posted you have to create a `ProjectRight` class which has references to `Project` and `AccessRight`.

Comment: Yep thanks, that's what I ended up using since I didn't want to create a `ProjectRight` class :)